# Java data structure for String and Class

Tags: java

I am looking to store information in a list or array, and then access the info through a method using a String parameter.

```
  public void blah(String name){
      DataStructure[apple].getInfo1; //a float
      DataStucture[apple].getInfo2; //an int
```

Some pseudocode of how the info will be stored:

```
     DataStructure.add(apple);
     apple.setFloat(5f);
     apple.setInt(1);
```

My main confusion is how to access this information using a String. Since I will be having a lot of objects in this structure, I figured the easiest way to access the info would be to look up the name directly.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but maybe you could use a `java.util.Map` (key = `"apple"`, value = `apple`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
public class DataStructure {
    private float info1;
    private int info2;
    public DataStructure(float info1, int info2) {
        super();
        this.info1 = info1;
        this.info2 = info2;
    }
    public float getInfo1() {
        return info1;
    }
    public void setInfo1(float info1) {
        this.info1 = info1;
    }
    public int getInfo2() {
        return info2;
    }
    public void setInfo2(int info2) {
        this.info2 = info2;
    }

}

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final HashMap<String, DataStructure> map = new HashMap<String, DataStructure>();

        map.put("apple", new DataStructure(5f, 1));

    }

}
```